# SDK issue - play-services-ads

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, sdk, google-play-services

i'm working in cordova project. my project using one plugin `cocoon-plugin-ads-android-admob`I need this plugin for monetization but This plugin works `<framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1"/>`. when i creating new realease in google play console, Google says this `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1 This SDK version has been reported as outdated. Upgrade to a newer version (19.3.0+).`

When I change in `project.properties`  `cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1` to `cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0` It changes, but the application crashes on startup. The app only works `16.0.0` and above no more. Is there any way to make this plugin work on `19.0.3+` versions? Or some alternative way to replace this plugin, This plugin works on `consturct 2` game project perfectli. Thanks in advance.